# Child element taking preference in accordian

Tags: jquery, parent-child

Hi, this is my first post! Hoping somebody might be able to help me out.

I am quite new to jQuery and scripting.

I have got an accordian type menu with 3 menu levels, with a particular level open on load.

The line within the second level is a span which will update the position of a Google Map using an onClick function.

Currently, clicking the span changes the map, but it **does not** activate the correct function of the accordian menu.

Please see this jfiddle: [1] (http://jsfiddle.net/chriscdk/WQhvR/1/)

When you click on Birmingham for example, the map would change (which you cannot see in the fiddle), but the corresponding links do not show. You need to click just off to the right (in the li) in order for that to work.

It is the same for trying to shrink the London menu.

(Both examples above are from the default load) I hope this explanation makes sense! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And how on earth are you supposed to create a proper link in a question?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<span>` elements around Birmingham and London are causing your script to fail the `if (this == event.target)` condition.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response - unfortunately, I need those spans - or at least something that will respond to the onClick event which will change the location of the Google Map. Is there any way around this?

Comment: maybe you could code a custom data attribute or an extra class into your <li> item instead of the span and then react to that

Comment: Thanks for the advice! My main concern was that clicking on any of the children elements of the <li> would then also move the map as above - but using code like this    $("li.category ul").click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
  }); has sorted out that issue. Thanks for your help and looking at this issue!